# Bootstrap Typeahead basic example not working in Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am trying to implement Bootstrap Typeahead to eventually use an Elasticsearch instance I have, but I cannot even get the basic example to work in Django (2.2.6). I am taking the majority of this code from the [examples](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) page. Here is the HTML I am using:

**typeahead.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
            return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                var matches, substringRegex;

                // an array that will be populated with substring matches
                matches = [];

                // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
                substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

                // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
                // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
                $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                    if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                        matches.push(str);
                    }
                });

                cb(matches);
            };
        };

        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
            'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
            'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
            'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
            'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
            'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
            'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
            'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
            'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
        ];

        $('.typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'states',
            source: substringMatcher(states)
        });
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="the-basics">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the page/URL I am trying to access:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'materials'

urlpatterns = [
    path('typeahead/', views.typeahead_view, name='typeahead')
]
```

And this is the basic view I have set up for this page:

**views.py**

```
def typeahead_view(request):
    return render(request, 'materials/typeahead.html')
```

Nothing happens when I start typing in the input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your html page. First of all, jquery was not added in it and secondly add all the js file at the end of the body. Check below updated code for the html file.

**typeahead.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="the-basics">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
            return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                var matches, substringRegex;

                // an array that will be populated with substring matches
                matches = [];

                // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
                substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

                // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
                // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
                $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                    if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                        matches.push(str);
                    }
                });

                cb(matches);
            };
        };

        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
            'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
            'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
            'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
            'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
            'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
            'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
            'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
            'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
        ];

        $('.typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'states',
            source: substringMatcher(states)
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works properly. I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it working using this [package](https://pypi.org/project/django-typeahead) (and some modifications), but your way is much cleaner!